# Time constraint before allowing low-rep users to delete own question with an answer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I would like to propose that new users not be able to delete their own questions too soon after receiving an answer. If we're going to prohibit a user from deleting their own question with an up-voted answer (as described by [How can a post be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)), it seems that we have to give the community a chance to actually see the answer and vote.

This question ([how to draw an inductor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035548/how-to-draw-an-inductor)) is not a great example (because it's not a great question, a little too localized), but I not only posted an answer, but did at least two additional substantial iterations of the answer as the user added additional constraints (as the question evolved from "how do I draw semi-circles" to "how do I do that in `drawRect`" to "how do I do that with CoreGraphics"). But as soon as I answered all of his follow-up questions, he promptly deleted the original question, probably less than two hours after he posted the original question and certainly before many people had a chance to see (much less vote on) my answer.

But I'm not looking for feedback on that particular question (while I have sinking suspicion that I just did someone's homework, but it's not clear that question is truly worthy of undeleting). I'm wondering about the broader practice. It strikes me that if up-voting is going to be a criterion for prohibiting deletion, then we have to have a window that lets the community see the answer and vote. Perhaps only let the user "vote" for the deletion of their question within the first few hours (if there is an answer).

It's just frustrating to invest so much time helping someone out, only to have it deleted with not so much as a "by your leave." (I was thinking of a more colorful metaphor, but I'll leave it there.)